# generalize map and reduce lab

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm working on a lab Using a generalized map method to pass an element and block through returning multiple outcomes.

Really struggled on this one. Found some responses but they don't really make sense to me.

Here is the code:

```
def map(s)
  new = []
  i = 0
  while i < s.length
    new.push(yield(s[i]))
    i += 1
  end
  new
end
```

Here's is the test:

```
  it "returns an array with all values made negative" do
    expect(map([1, 2, 3, -9]){|n| n * -1}).to eq([-1, -2, -3, 9])
  end

  it "returns an array with the original values" do
    dune = ["paul", "gurney", "vladimir", "jessica", "chani"]
    expect(map(dune){|n| n}).to eq(dune)
  end

  it "returns an array with the original values multiplied by 2" do
    expect(map([1, 2, 3, -9]){|n| n * 2}).to eq([2, 4, 6, -18])
  end

  it "returns an array with the original values squared" do
    expect(map([1, 2, 3, -9]){|n| n * n}).to eq([1, 4, 9, 81])
  end
end
```

I don't get how the above code can give you these 4 different results.

Could someone help me understand it ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: looks like your code is missing something

Comment: what part doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How your method `map` works**

To see how your method operates let's modify your code to add some intermediate variables and some `puts` statements to show the values of those variables.

```
def map(s)
  new = []
  i = 0
  n = s.length
  puts "s has length #{n}"
  while i < n
    puts "i = #{i}"
    e = s[i]
    puts "  Yield #{e} to the block"
    rv = yield(e)
    puts "  The block's return value is #{rv}. Push #{rv} onto new"
    new.push(rv)
    puts "  new now equals #{new}"
    i += 1
  end
  puts "We now return the value of new"
  new
end
```

Now let's execute the method with one of the blocks of interest.

```
s = [1, 2, 3, -9]
map(s) { |n| n * 2 }
  #=> [2, 4, 6, -18] (return value of method)
```

The following is displayed.

```
s has length 4
i = 0
  Yield 1 to the block
  The block's return value is 2. Push 2 onto new
  new now equals [2]
i = 1
  Yield 2 to the block
  The block's return value is 4. Push 4 onto new
  new now equals [2, 4]
i = 2
  Yield 3 to the block
  The block's return value is 6. Push 6 onto new
  new now equals [2, 4, 6]
i = 3
  Yield -9 to the block
  The block's return value is -18. Push -18 onto new
  new now equals [2, 4, 6, -18]
We now return the value of new
```

It may by of interest to execute this modified method with different values of `s` and different blocks.

**A replacement for `Array#map`?**

Is this a replacement for [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-map) (or [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), but for now let's just consider `Array#map`)? As you defined it at the *top level* your `map` is an instance method of the class `Object`:

```
Object.instance_methods.include?(:map) #=> true
```

It must be invoked `map([1,2,3]) { |n| ... }` whereas `Array#map` is invoked `[1,2,3].map { |n| ... }`. Therefore, for your method `map` to be a replacement for `Array#map` you need to define it as follows.

```
class Array
  def map
    new = []
    i = 0
    while i < length
      new.push(yield(self[i]))
      i += 1
    end
    new
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, -9].map { |n| n * 2 }
  #=> [2, 4, 6, -18]
```

**Simplify**

We can simplify this method as follows.

```
class Array
  def map
    new = []
    each { |e| new << yield(e) }
    new
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, -9].map { |n| n * 2 }
  #=> [2, 4, 6, -18]
```

or, better:

```
class Array
  def map
    each_with_object([]) { |e,new| new << yield(e) }
  end
end
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

Note that `while i < length` is equivalent to `while i < self.length`, because `self.`, if omitted, is implicit, and therefore redundant. Similarly, `each { |e| new << yield(e) }` is equivalent to `self.each { |e| new << yield(e) }` and `each_with_object([]) { ... }` is equivalent to `self.each_with_object([]) { ... }`.

**Are we finished?**

If we examine the doc [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-map) carefully we see that there are two forms of the method. The first is when `map` takes a block. Our method `Array#map` mimics that behaviour and that is the only behaviour needed to satisfy the given `rspec` tests.

There is a second form, however, where `map` is not given a block, in which case it returns an enumerator. That allows us to chain the method to another. For example (with Ruby's `Array#map`),

```
['cat', 'dog', 'pig'].map.with_index do |animal, i|
  i.even? ? animal.upcase : animal
end
  #=> ["CAT", "dog", "PIG"]
```

We could modify our `Array#map` to incorporate this second behaviour as follows.

```
class Array
  def map
    if block_given?
      each_with_object([]) { |e,new| new << yield(e) }
    else
      to_enum(:map)
    end
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, -9].map { |n| n * 2 }
  #=> [2, 4, 6, -18]
['cat', 'dog', 'pig'].map.with_index do |animal, i|
  i.even? ? animal.upcase : animal
end
  #=> ["CAT", "dog", "PIG"]
```

See [Kernel#block_given?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F) and [Object#to_enum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Object.html#method-i-to_enum).

**Notes**

You might use, say, `arr`, rather than `s` as the variable holding the array, as `s` often denotes a string, just as `h` typically denotes a hash. One generally avoids names for  variables and custom methods that are the names of core Ruby methods. That is also an objection to your use of `new` as a variable name, as there are many core methods named `new`.

Comment: If the exercise is to _write_ `map`, then delegating to Array/Enumerable is kind of cheating, no? :)

Comment: @Sergio, ha! It didn't occur to me that this was to be a replacement for THE map, though it is front-and-centre in the first sentence.

Comment: Got it! Thank you !!